# Cisco 2811 nat question

Tags: cisco, nat

I am trying to setup a cisco 2811 router for a lan party. So Far I have the following configuration. The router can ping the "outside" lan, but nothing from "inside" can see out.

```
ena

conf term

no ip domain lookup
no logging console

ip dhcp pool Main
 network 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
 default-router 172.16.0.1
 dns-server 4.2.2.1

exit

int Fa0/0

ip access-list standard 1
 permit 172.16.255.255
 deny any
 exit

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.0.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no shutdown
 ip nat inside


interface FastEthernet0/1
 no shutdown
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto



exit

ip nat inside source list 1 interface FA0/0
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FA0/1


exit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation is not correct.

You should use 
ip nat inside source list 1 interface "FA0/1 overload" instead of FA0/0

remember your outside interface is Fa0/1 and you want your LAN to exit through that interface IP

Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Unless you only want address 172.16.255.255 to be NAT'ed that access-list is wrong. It should be:

```
ip access-list standard 1
 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.255.255
 deny any
 exit
```

Comment: Oops, goofed that part up. Still is not working quite right yet.

Comment: Need a little more info to troubleshoot. Is your PC behind a switch or directly connected to fa0/0? Can you post a 'sh int fa0/1' ? Or a sh ip int brief to verify that your fa0/0 wan interface is getting its dhcp address from the isp provider?  From the router, can you try 'ping 4.2.2.1 source fa0/1' & also from fa0/0